# Is there a name for this punishment used in army?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is there any English name for this?

---

P.S. A comment asks if there is a name in another language. The punishment has the name in Korean. If I translate directly from Korean, it's 'bombing on Wonsan city'. Wonsan is a city in North Korea and the name might be originated from the Korean war. During the war, the alliance air force of the UN, USA, and South Korean did bombing on the city.

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific name for this, but you may find this link helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_punishment

Comment: In curious, does this have a name in some other language? Which, and what is it?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an example of corporal punishment

Comment: This also leads to major pain in the general area of the neck and soldiers. 